# Is it safe to do pthread_join on a thread that has been attached to JVM using JNI's AttachCurrentThread method

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, pthreads

when we attach a Cpp thread to the Java Native Interface (JNI) using the AttachCurrentThread (JavaVM *vm, void **p_env, void *thr_args) method, the C++ thread effectively becomes an external thread from the perspective of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

After Attaching the Native Cpp thread to JVM, if I do pthread_join on the attached thread or if the attached thread is abruptly terminated before getting Detach from JVM, Is there going to be an issue?

what I understand is when a native thread is attached to the JVM using AttachCurrentThread, the JVM allocates certain resources and maintains internal data structures to manage the thread's interaction with Java objects.
If the thread is abruptly terminated without being properly detached, these resources may not be released and could lead to memory leaks or other resource or JVM-related issues.

[image]

In the above code DeattachCurrentThread becomes unreachable and I have already did pthread_exit (), will this cause any issue related to memory leak or any other issue?

Comment: `pthread_join` by itself does nothing; it just waits for the thread to exit.

Comment: Why are you still using pthread? C++ had std::thread for 12 years now. And C++20 has std::jthread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to do pthread_join on a thread that has been attached to JVM using JNI's AttachCurrentThread method

There is no particular reason to think not.  Java and JNI have no more means to interfere with the thread than any other code has.

Note, too, that the JNI specifications require a thread that attaches to a JVM to detach itself again before terminating.  After such a detachment, there is *especially* no reason to think that the thread would exhibit any behavior inconsistent with pthreads.

Comment: I'm talking about the scenario where the native thread is not detached yet, if I do pthread_join, would there be any issues?

Comment: @Jatinguglani, the point about detachment is that if the thread adheres to JNI's requirements then it will no longer be attached when it terminates, and if it does not adhere to JNI requirements then the program is wrong.  But you are missing the larger point. Again: "*Java and JNI have no more means to interfere with the thread than any other code has.*"  There is nothing about attachment that makes joining a thread that at some point attaches to a JVM any more unsafe than joining any other thread.

Comment: Thanks I got your point, Could you please tell, me if the thread is abruptly terminated when it's been attached to JVM, will that cause any issues related to a memory leak or something else? check updated question for details

Comment: @Jatinguglani, as we already discussed, JNI requires that native threads not terminate while attached to a JVM.  That includes both normal and abrupt termination.  If a native thread were terminated while attached to a JVM then I would expect the JVM to be destabilized -- maybe only a little, or maybe a lot, depending on the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you help me with similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77021123/pros-cons-of-attaching-all-the-native-cpp-threadsof-a-thread-pool-to-jvm-on-cr